# what is the difference between maven-archetype-webapp and eclipse dynamic web project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

why do I need to apply: **mvn eclipse:eclipse** command?

are they **equivalent** to application container/server?

Is there a file for which customizing is necessary besides **web.xml**?

Answer (score 3):

when you create a web project using maven, like maven-archetype-webapp. It creates the folder structure as recommend by Maven for a webapp like shown [here](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-bundles/maven-archetype-webapp/) .

Now when you try to import these folders in Eclipse, it still would look like folders but eclipse cannot understand the nature of these folders. Eclipse relates folders and contents within them to an Eclipse dynamic web project only through its .project , .settings files

So in order for your maven project to be understood by Eclipse, you run the goal mvn eclipse:eclipse. After executing this goal, maven generates the .project, .settings files necessary for eclipse to understand the project as Web project.

This is however optional. You can still import the project as Maven projects within eclipse and continue to use them but you cant rely on Eclipse's features like clean/ build / build automatically.

Though I use eclipse, I dont rely on Eclipse's build feature. I have installed Maven eclipse plugin and that allows me to run maven goals and commands within Eclipse which is as good as running Eclipse's build feature. Hope this helps.

Comment: great answer! I wonder why there isn't a standard way of deploy applications, I mean, a web project created with RAD, MyEclipse, Netbeans or JDeveloper include certain files that are very specific for each product, i think that maven is closest tool to achieve a standard way of building webapps (or other archetypes) for now.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you mean by "a web project created with RAD, MyEclipse, Netbeans or JDeveloper include certain files that are very specific for each product". We can also generate those files using Maven in case you are trying to deploy to IBM Websphere application server.

Comment: I've seen that Integrated Development Environment add certain files to every webapp depending on if we wish to use a facet, a target runtime like tomcat or Glassfish, add JSF or JPA capabilities,in the case of IBM suite,in Rational Application Developer we have several XMI files